# Retrieve all the keys of JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I know these kinds of questions have been answered,but the solutions provided doesn't work for me at all. I want to retrieve all the keys in an JSON file, at every level, not just at the first level.

Let say I want to get all the keys from the following JSON file

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My progress so far

```
for k,v in json_object.items():
    print(v.keys())
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Gahan I am sorry for that, I didn't add my progress so I just asked how someone would approach a question from ground up. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Store you json content as dict in a variable i.e. `data` as:

```
data = {
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use the below recursive method to get all the keys...

```
def get_keys(d, indent=0, parent=""):
    print("{}{}{}{}".format(" "*indent*4, parent, " => " if parent else "", list(d.keys())))

    for key in d:
        if isinstance(d[key], dict):
            get_keys(d[key], indent=indent+1, parent=key)
```

When you call the method as below:

```
get_keys(data)
```

you would get Output as:

```
['quiz']
    quiz => ['sport', 'maths']
        sport => ['q1']
            q1 => ['question', 'options', 'answer']
        maths => ['q1', 'q2']
            q1 => ['question', 'options', 'answer']
            q2 => ['question', 'options', 'answer']
```